# When does Juju re-read feature flag environment variable?

Tags: juju

If you want to try out a new feature flag in Juju `JUJU_DEV_FEATURE_FLAG=...`, is there a way to tell Juju to re-read the environment variable or do you have to destroy and bootstrap your environment?

Answer (score 1):

Feature flags are only read at bootstrap time.